# ¿Cómo concatenar dos EditText para ser enviados por email?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quisiera que me ayudaran con un problema que tengo de concatenar tres valores de *Edit Text*, ya que son valores obtenidos de un pequeño formulario (nombre, apellido, teléfono) y estos valores serán enviados mediante *Edit Text*, este es el pequeño código que ya generé para que puedan ser enviados pero solamente me deja concatenar dos valores:

```
enviarEmail(etNom + etAp .getText().toString());
```

¿Cómo puedo concatenar tres, o como puedo concatenar los tres con una formula?

Por favor espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: si el primer se llama ET1 el otro ET2 el otro ET2
String texto1 = et1.getText();
String texto 2 = et2.getText();
String texto 3 = et3.getText();
Enbviaremail =texto1+texto2+texto3

(no recuerdo si lleva el .toString o no los gettext)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo concatenando sus valores que obtienes mediante `.getText().toString()` , este es un ejemplo:

```
enviarEmail(editText1.getText().toString() + " " + editText2.getText().toString()+ " " + editText3.getText().toString());
```